# Не работает Magnific popup

Tags: jquery, popup

Не работает [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), если контент изменился асинхронно.

Есть календарик на [сайте](http://vsebe.ru.95-213-203-160.brho.ru), но при смене месяца на `Апрель` модальное окно при клике на дату не открывается, хотя после перезагрузки страницы работает.
Вызывал окно

```
$(".popup").magnificPopup({
       type: 'inline'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что на момент загрузки страницы Апреля еще не было.

```
$('#Calendar').on('click','.popup',function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: '#popup_form_cal',
            type: 'inline'
        }
    });
});
```